# Parse custom datetime in Pig

Tags: datetime, hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following as string `"2014-12-15 18:20:48"` but when I parsed to datetime:

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (mydate:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(mydate) as datetime;
```

I get this error: `"2014-12-15 18:20:48" is malformed at " 18:20:48"`
Alternatively, when I specify the format `ToDate(mydate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');` the datetime is converted to `"2014-12-15T18:20:48.000Z"` instead of `"2014-12-15 18:20:48"`. How can I resolve this to give me `"2014-12-15 18:20:48"` type datetime?

Comment: The return type of ToDate() function is Joda DateTime object (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date). What is your objective, if you like to have it as string in any other date format you can use toString(http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string) function.

Answer (score 0):

If we are passing string to ToDate function, the string should be of iosstring format(ref [1]).

ToDate(iosstring)

In the first case, the input string is not of iosstring format (T separator is missing, which signifies the beginning of time element). If the input string is 
of iosstring format(ref [1]) it will work.

In second case, you are calling overloaded method of ToDate :

ToDate(userstring, format)

The return type of all ToDate method is DateTime object.

If you are getting a date in string and you need it in any other format for further processsing then you have to use ToString() method on top of ToDate() method to get it in the 
desired format.

**References :**

1. iostring format : http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
2. ToDate(): http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date
3. ToString() : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string